# Confusing text "Search options not deleted" on search results page

Tags: feature-request, search, wording

When [doing a search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=test), the search results header shows a confusing text:

> Search options **not deleted**

While this is correct, it only shows non-deleted posts, it may lead to confusion: most users don't have the ability to search for deleted content, and users unfamiliar with Stack Exchange's "soft" deletion system may be utterly baffled - if something is deleted, how can it be shown at all?

My suggestion is that 'not deleted' should *not* be listed like a search option, like it was [last February](https://web.archive.org/web/20220222085618/http://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%25s). If you use the `deleted:1` option, showing 'Search options **deleted**' is fine.

---

[image]

A similar text is shown [when there are no search results](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22lednifrolg%22).

Comment: I was confused because I thought it meant that my search options hadn't been deleted. Also why would it only show the "not deleted" option, when there are also other default search options such as `is:question` and `is:answer`?